# Двойное исполнение скрипта на мобильном устройстве

Tags: javascript

Возникла проблема с исполнением скрипта после отправки формы, на десктопной версии все тип-топ, а вот на мобильной версии элемент

```
.after('<h1 class="fancy-success">Спасибо за заявку!</h1> <p class="fancy-success">с вами свяжутся в ближайшее время</p>')
```

вставляется дважды . В чем может быть загвоздка? Вот **скрипт**:

```
<script>

    $(function(){

        $('#contact').submit(function(){
            var errors = false;
            $(this).find('span').empty();

            $(this).find('input, textarea').each(function(){
                if( $.trim( $(this).val() ) == '' ) {
                    errors = true;
                    $(this).next().text( 'Не заполнено поле ' + $(this).prev().text() );
                }
            });

            if( !errors ){
                var data = $('#contact').serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data,
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $('#submit').next().text('Отправляю...');
                    },
                    success: function(res){
                        if( res == 1 ){
                            // $('#contact').find('input:not(#submit), textarea').val('');

                            $("#contact").hide('slow').after('<h1 class="fancy-success">Спасибо за заявку!</h1> <p class="fancy-success">с вами свяжутся в ближайшее время</p>');
                        }else{
                            $('#submit').next().empty();
                            alert('Ошибка отправки');
                        }
                    },

                    error: function(){
                        alert('Ошибка!');
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Склоняюсь, что у вас два раза отрабатывает `success`.
Сделайте `console.log()`  и посмотрите, сколько раз отработает (1).

Возможно у вас на элементе и onTap и onClick.

Потом я бы залогировал происходящее в `index.php` на колличество записей на одно обращение (2).

Временно можно использовать такой подход:

```
$('#contact').submit(function(e) {
    var me = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();

    if( me.data('requestRunning') )  return;

    me.data('requestRunning', true);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(msg){},
        error: function(){},
        complete: function() {
            me.data('requestRunning', false);
        }
    });      
});
```

В общем для начало, нужно знать (1) и (2)...
Пишите в комментариях.